# ubuntu 16.04 boot problem from usb

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a 32gb USB drive. With 200mb efi, 25gb ext4 and 2gb swap. When it finish I restart and select boot to start Ubuntu and I saw some meaningless characters like this:
http://uupload.ir/files/11bf_wp_20180223_04_56_46_pro.jpg

How can I fix it??

Comment: Try installing to the 32gb USB drive from a Live USB made using mkusb or latest UNetbootin, while the USB is booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: thank you. i changed the 200 MB partition to FAT32 and install again. everything is right now.